# Trying to get back to Win 7 after deleting Ubuntu 15.04. Can't get past "grub rescue >"

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, grub, grub2

I wanted to go back to an all Windows machine after trying Ubuntu 15.04. It was a good experiment, but not for me.

I had installed Ubuntu 15.04 on its own partition and it put in a dual boot menu. At start-up I chose either Ubuntu or Win 7.

After making the decision to delete Ubuntu, I went into the Disk Manager in Windows and used the Delete Volume command to free up the space. That left me with all free space where I had Ubuntu.

When I rebooted thinking I would go straight to Windows, I get the `grub rescue >` prompt and can't figure out what to do to get back into Windows.

I have read several of the other fixes in this forum, but they all seem to be aimed at recovering the Ubuntu partition and not to getting past the rescue screen and back to Windows.

How do I get my system to boot Windows now?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do (in your case) is writing a Windows MBR to hard disk.

With any Windows 7/8/10 installation/recovery CD/DVD/USB you can do this going to command prompt and using following command:

```
bootsect /nt60 all /mbr
```